# How to extract the area tag specifically using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database which has a table called `CNSMR_ACCNT_TAG`.  This table has a number of `cnsmr_accnts` with associated tags identified by means of a `tag_id`.  This table is linked to the Tag table by means of `tag_id`.  The Tag table is linked to the `tag_typ` table by means of the `tag_typ_id`. So...

```
Select * from cnsmr_accnt_tag cat inner join tag t on cat.tag_id = t.tag_id inner join tag_typ tt on t.tag_typ_id = tt.tag_typ_id
```

There are various types of tags some of which are exclusive - eg a consumer account can only be in one area at a time but may be in several tasks.  So you would have ONE active area tag but potentially 1 or several task tags.

I need to get a bunch of data about the `cnsmr_accnt` including which area it's in.

What I have been doing is to have a query with a subquery to return the area.  The downside of this approach is that there are a lot of accounts and bringing back the area for ALL `cnsmr_accnts` is slow. Is there a better way to write such a query so that I bring back the area for each account?

The query I am running is basically as follows:

```
Select distinct
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_lgcy_txt, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') as ACCNT_NUMBER
,AREA
,[wrkgrp_nm]
,wrkgrp_shrt_nm
,other_fields_here
from cnsmr c 
inner join cnsmr_accnt ca 
on c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id inner join wrkgrp w on c.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id inner join cnsmr_accnt_tag cat 
on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cat.cnsmr_accnt_id 
inner join tag t 
on cat.tag_id = t.tag_id 
inner  join tag_typ tt 
on t.tag_typ_id = tt.tag_typ_id
inner join 
(select cnsmr_accnt_id, tag_nm as AREA from tag t inner join tag_typ tt
on t.tag_typ_id = tt.tag_typ_id 
inner join cnsmr_accnt_tag cat on
t.tag_id = cat.tag_id 
where
tag_typ_shrt_nm = 'AREA'
and cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N') as AREA_TAG on 
cat.cnsmr_accnt_id = AREA_TAG.cnsmr_accnt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CROSS APPLY` for this? I hope I didn't muddle up your syntax... You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(cnsmr_accnt_idntfr_lgcy_txt, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') AS ACCNT_NUMBER
    ,T.AREA
    ,[wrkgrp_nm]
    ,wrkgrp_shrt_nm
    ,other_fields_here
FROM cnsmr c 
INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt ca 
    ON c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id 
INNER JOIN wrkgrp w 
    ON c.wrkgrp_id = w.wrkgrp_id 
INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt_tag cat 
    ON ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cat.cnsmr_accnt_id 
INNER JOIN tag t 
    ON cat.tag_id = t.tag_id 
INNER JOIN tag_typ tt 
    ON t.tag_typ_id = tt.tag_typ_id
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
         cnsmr_accnt_id
        ,tag_nm as AREA
    FROM tag t 
    INNER JOIN tag_typ tt
        ON t.tag_typ_id = tt.tag_typ_id 
    INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt_tag cat 
        ON t.tag_id = cat.tag_id 
    WHERE cat.cnsmr_accnt_id = AREA_TAG.cnsmr_accnt_id
    AND tag_typ_shrt_nm = 'AREA'
    AND cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg = 'N'
) T
;
```

There's a fantastic (and very detailed) explanation of how `CROSS APPLY` can sometimes outperform `INNER JOIN` [here](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/).

If each tag_id can only return one area, then this might just do the trick.  Rather than selecting the entirety of your previous `JOIN` result set and then connecting it to your outer query, this will only pull the first row of the sub-query for each consumer account, which I guessed is what you're looking for.  If I was wrong, I apologize ahead of time :)